# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment?
Error Coming Above

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method=='POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        desc = request.form['desc']
    todo = Todo(title=title,desc=desc)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    
    allTodo = Todo.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', allTodo=allTodo)
```

How to solve this issue

Comment: `title` is not defined if the request method is `GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a default value for `title`, either before your if-statement or as an `else` clause as a quick fix.

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    title = None  # <---- or whatever will work with your Todo mapper / database
    desc = None # same as above
    if request.method=='POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        desc = request.form['desc']
    todo = Todo(title=title,desc=desc)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    
    allTodo = Todo.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', allTodo=allTodo)
```

However, if it doesn't make sense to write anything to the database on a 'GET' request anyway, maybe you just need indentation to avoid the issue

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method=='POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        desc = request.form['desc']
        todo = Todo(title=title,desc=desc)
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit()
    
    allTodo = Todo.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', allTodo=allTodo)
```